# How to select mutiple values from excel single cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have excel cell having multiple rows of data with image url.

Now I want to select all images having 1500 value. So basically I want to select row starting with `http` and ending 1500.jpg.

Please not that in my single cell values are also other than 1500.jpg.Sample data is given below

```
colorImages': { 'initial': [{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71GOT-L%2BOSL._UL1500_.jpg","variant":"MAIN","lowRes":null},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/716mECZ9JDL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/313QD20m4WL._SR38,50_.jpg","large""thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/313QD20m4WL._SR38,50_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/313QD20m4WL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71GOT-L%2BOSL._UY445_.jpg":[445,117],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71GOT-L%2BOSL._UY500_.jpg":[500,132],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71GOT-L%2BOSL._UY550_.jpg":[550,145],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71GOT-L%2BOSL._UY606_.jpg":[606,160],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71GOT-L%2BOSL._UY679_.jpg":[679,179],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71GOT-L%2BOSL._UY741_.jpg":[741,195],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71GOT-L%2BOSL._UY879_.jpg":[879,231]},
```

Comment: so the above text in a single cell and you want a formula which extract the multiple value, Am I right?

Comment: yes,all complete urls having 1500 values

Comment: Provide more context and what you have tried. Why do you have that kind of data in Excel in the first place? Where does it come from? What do you want to achieve. This is not a script writing service, so explain your approach so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: I have my clients product image data in excel cell and i don't have idea how to extract product image urls having 1500.jpg values.

Comment: first need to find the count of 1500.jpg in each row. and then move from end to start and pull out the string from1500.jpg to https. e.g , if the count of 1500.jpg in 1st row is 3, then run a script 3 times and pull out the strings from 1500.jpg to http.

Comment: why would you ever put multiple data into one cell?? it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming data is in `Column A` starting from `Cell A2` and all the URLs ending with `1500.jpg` needs to be displayed in adjacent columns i.e. same row `Column B, Column C, Column D,....` then following might help.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, colIndex As Long
    Dim rng As Range, cel
    Dim X As Long, DotCount As Long
    Dim Pat As String, EndPat As String, Parts() As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")  'change Sheet3 to your data sheet
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row        'get last row with data in Column A
        For Each cel In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1))    'loop through A2 to last cell with data in Column A
            colIndex = 1

            Pat = "*[!&-;?-[_a-z~=!" & Chr$(1) & "]."
            EndPat = "[!&-;?-[_a-z~=!" & Chr$(1) & "]*"
            Parts = Split(cel.Value, """")      'split cell value into an array
            For X = 0 To UBound(Parts)
              If Parts(X) Like "*?.?*" Then
                DotCount = Len(Parts(X)) - Len(Replace(Parts(X), ".", ""))
                If """" & Replace(Parts(X), "]", Chr$(1)) & """" Like Application.Rept(Pat, DotCount) & EndPat Then
                    Parts(X) = ""
                ElseIf Right(Parts(X), 8) <> "1500.jpg" Then
                    Parts(X) = ""
                Else
                    cel.Offset(0, colIndex) = Parts(X)  'display URL
                    colIndex = colIndex + 1
                End If
              Else
                Parts(X) = ""
              End If
            Next X
        Next cel
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Derived this solution using `Function URLs` from [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/963028-extracting-multiple-urls-cell-containing-urls-plus-text.html).

Comment: For above sample data having only one url,it is working properly but for bulk data haivng many *1500* urls not working.

Comment: @TahirSatti - See image attached, I've used multiple URLs with results. It should for any number of URLs.

Comment: Please run code for following values.    colorImages': { 'initial': [{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71GOT-L%2BOSL._UL1500_.jpg","variant":"MAIN","lowRes":null},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/716mECZ9JDL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/313QD20m4WL._SR38,50_.jpg","large"

Comment: @TahirSatti - `I want to select row starting with http and ending 1500.jpg` this is what you have written in the question. In the above comment which is `colorImages': { 'initial': [{"hiRes":"images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/…},{"hiR‌​es":"images-na.ssl-i‌​mages-amazon.com/ima‌​ges/I/…` there's neither `http` nor `1500.jpg`, that's why its not returning anything.

Comment: thanks actully my text having following value i.e 1500_.jpg

Comment: @TahirSatti - If you can provide sample text containing multiple URLs satisfying the condition then I can check with my solution.

Comment: check following please

Comment: colorImages': { 'initial': [{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71GOT-L%2BOSL._UL1500_.jpg","variant":"MAIN","lowRes":null},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/716mECZ9JDL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/313QD20m4WL._SR38,50_.jpg","large"

Comment: @TahirSatti - I guess comment is not displaying text completely, you can add text in question for reference.

Comment: now i updated my question with sample data,Please check

Comment: @TahirSatti - Text added in questin has 12 URLs but none of them end with `1500.jpg`

Comment: As i said url have 1500_.jpg not 1500.jpg there is some issue in initial sample data,please conside 1500_.jpg thanks

Comment: @TahirSatti - Oops! I missed `1500_.jpg` in the comments above. Just change `ElseIf Right(Parts(X), 8) <> "1500.jpg" Then` to `ElseIf Right(Parts(X), 9) <> "1500_.jpg" Then`.

Answer (score 0):

This is done easily via VBA, but am not expert in that. So I have done some thing for you,just follow the instruction , still it is apply to get only single search entry i.e. means in a cell its find only one 1500.jpg entry.

To get second entry in the same cell you need some effort via change or get substring from the G1 Cell string and repeat the step as explained again.

1. In A1 Cell, put 1500.jpg
2. In B1 Cell, put your actual string as you have above
3. In C1 cell, put formula "=SEARCH(A1,B1)", which find the search 1500 in string
4. In D1 cell, put formula "=MID(B1,1,C1)", which extract the substring
5. For E1 we need reverse the string via VBA code - Add `Reversestr` function (To add this function, see [this link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1146-excel-reverse-string-word-order.html))
6. In F1 cell, put formula "=SEARCH(CHAR(34),E1)", which search " in above reverse string
7. In G1 cell, put formula "=MID(B1,C1-F1+1,C1)"

Finally you get the string in G1 Cell as `"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71GOT-L%2BOSL._1500.jpg"`
For VBa formula, check this links

http://analystcave.com/excel-substring-vba-substring/